# VSCode preview markdown by default

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

99.999999999% of my work with markdown files is reading. Can I enable preview mode by default for this files?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I tried this in `VS Code 1.48.1`

#### Method 1

Open a markdown (`*.md`) file, then open the **Command Palette** and select `>View: Reopen Editor With...` > `Markdown Preview (Experimental)`.

#### Method 2

Add these lines to your `settings.json` file

```json
{
    // your other settings ...
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor",
            "filenamePattern": "*.md"
        }
    ],
}
```

#### Method 3

I am using `VS Code 1.61.2` this worked, as I also had some other mappings in the settings.json

```
{
    // your other settings ...
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor"
        }
    ],
}
```

#### Method 4

VSCode team change this configuration, I'm using v1.63.2

```
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {   
        "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor",
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 2 is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @InfoStatus if you double click anywhere in the preview tab VSCode will open the document in edit mode.

Comment: This syntax is changed in newer versions (at least in 1.59): `"workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor"}`

Comment: Now the diff editor opens markdown as previews, how to fix that?

Comment: Method 4 also works perfectly for me. The three first methods' syntax doesn't work any longer. 

`"workbench.editorAssociations": { "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor"}`

Comment: None of these worked for me. I had to open a Markdown file, bring up de command palette and follow these steps: "Reopen Editor With..." > "Cofigure default editor for *.md" > "Markdown preview"

Comment: Option 4 works great, thanks. A top tip - double click the preview to go into edit mode, took me a while to accidentally find that one.

Comment: Ctrl+P: Markdown: Toggle Preview Locking

Comment: Damn I love this! This made my day!

Comment: Any way to add an exception not to preview when in diff mode?

Answer (score 13):

To fix this through the UI settings:

1. Find the Workbench: Editor Associations setting
2. Click Add Item
3. In the Key field put `*.md` and in the Value field put `vscode.markdown.preview.editor`
4. Click OK

Answer (score 5):

If you not only want to read the `.md` files, I would recommend to you the [Markdown All in One](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one) VS Code extension.

It provides many useful [keyboard shortcuts](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one#keyboard-shortcuts) and also `.md` file preview, that allows you to edit files and view the relevance of the changes at the same moment.

Comment: With this one you can also set `"markdown.extension.preview.autoShowPreviewToSide": true`