# How can I open a .md file in VS Code preview mode from terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code has a good preview mode for .md files. To open a file with this mode, I have to right-click the file in VS Code document tree, and click "Open Preview". One can also use shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

I would like to open a .md file in VS Code preview mode *directly from Ubuntu's terminal*.

I guess the command I'm looking for will be something like
`code README.md --preview` ... but running `code --help` didn't help me to find my answer.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: It would be fewer keystrokes just to type `code README.md` and then Ctrl-Shift-V to open the preview.

Comment: If you're okay with Markdown files _always_ opening in preview mode (at first—you can switch to text-edit mode afterwards), see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541437/13170908

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open VSCode settings.json file with;

- Ctrl Shift P
- Preferences: Open User Settings

Add these lines to json file before the last }

```
    , // don't forget the comma
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {   
        "*.md": "vscode.markdown.preview.editor",
    }
```

Then whenever you want, you can use `code README.md` command.