VSCode command line opens wrong markdown editor
I am using vscode-office extension to edit markdown files (WYSIWYG).
It works fine with one exception.
When file editor is launched directly from command line i.e. code readme.md it opens default inbuilt markdown editor instead of vscode-office one. So I have to switch editors manually.
Running code . produces correct markdown editor.
Hacking as described here produces correct markdown editor as well.
Am I missing a better solution? Is there a command-line argument or some setting?
PS. Turning off Workspace trust helps as well. (Security->Workspace->Trust: Enabled). This works when launched from Windows (shortcut of Edit with..) but not when lauched from terminal.
PPS VSCode 1.67.1 (latest Win7 version)

have you followed an adjusted version of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60155443/11107541 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/73049432/11107541 ?

@starball I am using a bit difirrent extension. Turning off Workspace trust helps as well.

if vscode does not support this natively and otherwise the solution seems hacky this might be a good opportunity to dive into writing your own binaries which can be called directly if it in a folder like usr/local/bin or simply by creating an alias if it is just a command
