# How to automatically open the Markdown Preview side by side in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

When I'm writing Markdown (`*.md`) files in VS Code I often need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>V</kbd> to open up the [Markdown Preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview) panel on the side. I'm trying to optimize my process and have this done automatically for me whenever I open a Markdown file. Please note I do not want to install any additional extension for this, I just want the built-in Markdown Preview provided by VS Code.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a way to have this automatically open.  I thought "Method 4" found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63541437/6530134) might be it, but all that does is open your markdown files in the preview mode instead.

Comment: @TimothyG. I saw that answer as well but it wasn't what I was looking for so I didn't even bother trying.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hnw.vscode-auto-open-markdown-preview for those who find this question, but accept to install extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Markdown All in One Extension first.

Try to find the 'Auto Show Preview To Side' option in the **Settings**, just like in the screenshot below.

Cheers!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXcid.png)